# What happened to Ro Laren's nose ridges?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-picard

In Star Trek:Picard Ro Laren appears without her Bajoran nose ridges. What happened to them? Was she surgically altered?

Comment: I don't recall seeing Ro appear on Picard- What episode?

Comment: The latest episode season 3 ep 5

Comment: Maybe she just had "some work done".  Seriously, maybe for an undercover assignment and when her Bajoran appearance was restored they didn't get it quite right.

Comment: "Prophets!  I hate getting older.  Seems like every time I look in the mirror, there's one less wrinkle."

Comment: What happened to them?  Absolutely nothing.   Honestly, this question shouldn't be so upvoted.

Comment: @ThePopMachine I disagree. sno missed the nose ridges, but as alexg mentioned, the lighting of the set can make things hard to discern. They've darkened the whole set for...a depressive effect? Also, when I first saw Ro's ridges, they appeared miniscule to me. The prosthesis could have changed in size.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

She does have nose ridges:

[image: Ro Laren (Michelle Forbes) in Star Trek: Picard S3E05]

(image from https://www.giantfreakinrobot.com/ent/star-trek-ro-laren-picard.html)

These look to be about the same as her nose when she last appeared, in "Preemptive Strike" (The Next Generation, S7E24; image from https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Ro_Laren):

[image: Ro Laren in Star Trek: The Next Generation S7E24]

It has been about 30 years in real time and within the Star Trek chronology, but this is very much the same nose, with the same number of ridges. Different makeup, lighting and filming technology might have made the prosthesis less obvious than it was in TNG.

In her first appearances, she had extra ridges extending over her eyebrows, like other Bajorans. This was changed as an element of Bajoran makeup, for artistic reaons, but has never been explained in-universe. If there is an in-universe explanation, then whatever happened would have taken place during the course of the Enterprise-D's mission in The Next Generation, and not in the intervening years.

Comment: Can always blame a transporter accident or a head-butt from a Klingon, if aging isn't enough.

Comment: a very busy Klingon, since it happened to other Bajorans as well